# best way to allocate memory in C for parallel programming openmp and mpi

Tags: c, parallel-processing

If one were to write C code, not C++, and were to use openmp directives to make a parallel program then what is the best way to allocate memory?
I am used to the traditional malloc() and calloc() but i have also come across

```
#include <sys/sem.h>
```

for doing semaphores.
Is one better or worse than the other?

The program i am considering writing would be using large amounts of RAM, on the order of 256GB or more.  And it would also be reading/writing scratch files greater than 4GB.  Therefore i would not be using the 32-bit version of the `lseek()` command but would use `lseek64()`.
With all that in mind, can someone offer advice for the best way to write such a program?
I had learned openmp a long time ago, and that generally will suffice for running on a single system having enough memory, but I mentioned MPI because i would be ok learning and using that instead if it makes everything more robust and portable.  Or some other method of parallel programming in C.

Answer (score 0):

consider using mmap and mremap for faster remapping of memory as mremap() uses the Linux page table scheme.